# How to respond with 403 (forbidden) for index action on nested resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, pundit

Suppose we have the following setup in a ruby-on-rails (API) application:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :friends, class_name: User # Via a joins table....
end

class Post
  belongs_to :user
end
```

When visiting `/users/:id/posts`, I want the logged-in user to only be able to view this data, if they are friends.

The standard implementation for this in Pundit is to use a [policy scope](https://github.com/elabs/pundit#scopes):

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate
  def index
    posts = policy_scope(Post.where(user_id: params[:user_id]))
    render posts
  end
end

class PostsPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < ApplicationPolicy::Scope
    def resolve
      scope.where(user: user.friends)
    end
  end
end
```

This *will* prevent a user from seeing non-friends' posts. However, **it produces an API response of `200 Success`** (with an empty response body), not `403 Forbidden` - which would be preferable for the FrontEnd to receive, and display an appropriate error message.

---

Here's one solution that does **not** work:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate
  def index
    posts = policy_scope(Post.where(user_id: params[:user_id]))
    authorize posts # <- !!!!
    render posts
  end
end

class PostsPolicy
  def index?
    record.all? { |post| user.friends_with?(post.user) }
  end
end
```

Not only is this very inefficient, but if the user *doesn't have any posts*, then you'll always get a `200 Success` response - which is still not ideal.

Similarly, it's not ideal to "return `403` if the response is empty" - because then you'd get error messages when viewing friends' posts, if they don't have any!

---

Here's a possible solution, but it feels *wrong*...

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate
  def index
    user = user.find(params[:user_id])
    authorize(user, :index_posts?) # <-- !!!!

    posts = policy_scope(Post.where(user: user))
    render posts
  end
end

class UsersPolicy
  def index_posts?
    user.friends_with?(record)
  end
end
```

(You could also use a more generic method name like `UserPolicy#friends?`, to the same affect.)

This works, but it feels like a mis-use of Pundit to be applying a `UserPolicy` method when authorising a `Post` resource!

---

Pundit does not allow [passing additional arguments to policies](https://github.com/elabs/pundit/blob/master/README.md#additional-context). This has been a [highly requested](https://github.com/elabs/pundit/issues/372) feature over the years. In particular, see [this highly-relevant PR/discussion](https://github.com/elabs/pundit/pull/50#issuecomment-56638288). In other words, what I'd *like* to be able to do is this:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate
  def index
    user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    posts = policy_scope(Post.where(user: user))
    authorize(posts, user) # <- !!!! (not valid in Pundit)
    render posts
  end
end

class PostsPolicy
  def index?(other_user) # <- !!!! (not valid in Pundit)
    user.friends_with?(other_user)
  end
end
```

However, the feature was eventually conclusively rejected by the project maintainer in favour of using "name-spaced policies" and "form objects".

---

Hopefully this question is not too "opinionated", but what would you suggest? Is there a clean way to use the Pundit library whilst responding with appropriate `200` vs `403` appropriately?

Or, is there a good patch/fork/alternative I could use (preferably easy to migrate to, for a large project) that will better support my desired behaviour?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/elabs/pundit/issues/351#issuecomment-310665553) is another possible workaround, possibly in conjunction with [this pending fix](https://github.com/elabs/pundit/pull/391) for name-spaced policy scopes?

Comment: you are showing the posts#index page when they clicked on the link regardless if the current_user is a friend of users/:id or not right? Then I think you'd want a 200 then but then maybe not use the term "authorize" but more like I guess think of the posts as being "filtered"? But if you really don't show these posts#index page if not a friend (i.e. you dont show the links if not a friend) then I think 403 response is better.

Comment: I would also do something like what you said `authorize(user, :index_posts?)` but except that I'd name it as `authorize(user, :posts?)`, because technically speaking /users/:id/posts, the "posts" there is part of the resources of /users/:id which means posts#index is technically a resource of a member of users, though I agree that this does not seem to be RESTful-like. However, this approach works also for other nested resources. i.e. if you'll have in the future something like /categories/1/posts, then it is flexible enough to also implement a category_policy#posts? method in the same way.

Comment: On a side note, I am not really familiar with pundit, but we've been using [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) to a great success. It handles [nested resources](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Nested-Resources) pretty well, although in my experience cancancan can get very confusing at the start of learning.

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario This is a rails API project (i.e. all responses are in JSON; the Front-End is a separate JavaScript project). So the `403` response is particularly valuable in terms of providing a coherent API definition. I do prefer your naming of `UserPolicy#posts?` over my initial `index_posts?` though -- this seems more logical.

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario I have no intention of migrating to `CanCanCan`, however... This is a very large project, so the migration time alone makes this infeasible. It's also, in my opinion, a far more difficult/problematic library to work with than Pundit. (Building all your `abilities` in a one big class is a bad idea when your application is big ... )

Comment: ohh yeah this is an API! :) I think 403 is better just because the client-side will know from this response code that the current user is not a friend as opposed to returning a 200 empty response, which can be misleading (as either the current user is not a friend OR it just happened that the target user's posts is just empty). It also makes...

Comment: ...sense that the client side cannot view (forbidden) to view this posts#index resource if not a friend. I think it is the client-side's duty to handle a 403 like this, and that the client-side should not render the links to this resource in the first place because it will be forbidden as the current user is not a friend.

Comment: yeah it does get so biiiiig! haha. We resorted to segregating the ability.rb file by including a Module per resource.